# how to set a default output message in react speech recognition?

Tags: reactjs

I am using a web speech API to create a speech recognition app in Reactjs. So I've given two commands
and trying to get output using speech and I am getting output the same as I set. but the problem is when I am saying something else instead of set commands it is returning the previous output.
how to fix this problem like I want to set a default message when user's input is not matching that message should be output...
code .....

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import SpeechRecognition, {
  useSpeechRecognition,
} from "react-speech-recognition";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  let [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const commands = [
    {
      command: "hello",
      callback: () => setMessage("Hi... how can i help you ?"),
      matchInterim: true,
    },
    {
      command: "how are you",
      callback: () => setMessage("I am good ........."),
      matchInterim: true,
    },
  ];
  const { transcript } = useSpeechRecognition({ commands });
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="headerText">
        <h1>Speech Recognition App</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="output-container">
        <p>{transcript}?</p>
        <p>{transcript ? message : "Say something........."}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="button-container">
        <button className="btn-1" onClick={SpeechRecognition.startListening}>
          Start Listening
        </button>

        <button className="btn-2" onClick={SpeechRecognition.stopListening}>
          Stop Listening
        </button>
        <button className="btn-3" onClick={needtoadd}>
          Reset
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: Please show us the code you have so we can advice. In the absence of that it's impossible to say, because there are a too many different ways one could implement this.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following:

identify when a new "interpretation" is underway

```
const [UnhandledCommand,SetUnhandledCommand] = useState<boolean>(false);
if (interimTranscript.length > 0) 
{
  if (!UnhandledCommand) SetUnhandledCommand(true);
}
```

identify when the interpretation has ended

```
if (interimTranscript === "" && transcript === finalTranscript && transcript.length > 0)
{
   if (UnhandledCommand) 
   {
     the default command ...
   }
}
```

all command handlers will have to set UnhandledCommand to false;

Answer (score 0):

You are getting previous message because you are not updating state with the default message. In the callback function you are updating message when it matched but you are not updating message state when it does not match that's why you are getting previous message.

To resolve this you can use Switch Case so when the command will match state will be updated accordingly otherwise update state by default message.

```
matchCommand(data) {
  data.map(item => {
    switch (item.command) {
      case "hello": 
        // Set the state instead of returning a function that sets the state
        setMessage("Hi... how can i help you ?");
        break;
      case "how are you": 
        setMessage("I am good .........");
        break;
      default: 
        setMessage("Default message");
        break;
    };
  }); 
}
```